# Triage queue - closing off-topic, no code questions

Tags: discussion, support, triage

I've been helping with the triage queue for about a week now and wanted to double check some of my flags, since I have 13 disputed flags and 15 helpful flags.

Most of my disputed flags are close votes based on "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers."

Some of my disputed flags are for questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276970/how-to-display-data-listview-in-pdf-format-in-c-sharp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239379/android-how-to-change-listview-item-ui-without-press-on-him), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204668/onmouseover-window-location-this-href-what-code-to-make-link-opening-on-new-ta), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148297/image-processing-in-dsk-6713).

All of these questions are:

- Seeking debugging help
- Have a more or less clear problem statement
- And are **lacking** the shortest code necessary to reproduce the error

In these cases, I typically cast a close vote because they are missing the code - and the "Should be improved" button won't help because we don't have the OP's code.

It seems that my helpful to disputed flag ratio is hovering around 1:1. Is there a better way to handle these types of questions than a flag? Is there a better flag to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me get this out the way:  **disputed flags don't hurt you.** It just means that someone else disagreed with your flag by taking some kind of action on the post.

That being said, all but one of those questions are too broad (and the last one I seem to have preempted myself by a week by voting to close).

I'm not sure why you think all of them are lacking the necessary code to reproduce the described problem; your third example has executable code in it which replicates the scenario and describes what a desired outcome should be.  That one *isn't* too broad in my evaluation.

I'd recommend flagging when a question is irredeemable, and downvoting when a question isn't clear or useful, but *could* be edited or brought back in line.

Comment: That's the triage queue, voting disabled.

Comment: Which is partially why I was opting for flags. It seemed to be the appropriate negative action since "Should be improved" is true, but any queue it'd go to then wouldn't help since the question is lacking OP's information, not information that another user could provide.

Comment: Don't paint all questions with the same brush.  The JavaScript question could be improved, but the others were definitely VTC-worthy.

Answer (score 4):

[how to display data listView in pdf format in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276970/how-to-display-data-listview-in-pdf-format-in-c-sharp) is too broad.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239379/android-how-to-change-listview-item-ui-without-press-on-him is answerable, though low quality. Also, it seems to be a dupe.

[onmouseover="window.location=this.href" what code to make link opening on new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204668/onmouseover-window-location-this-href-what-code-to-make-link-opening-on-new-ta) I'm sure that's a dupe somewhere, but that would be the only reason to close it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30148297/image-processing-in-dsk-6713 Not sure about this one, some voted to close as "too broad" though. Certainly seems downvote-worthy.

---

Anyway, don't agonize over disputed flags, you'll get quite a lot in that queue. Only helpful and declined flags are considered for extra-flags and flag-bans.