# How to review Triage questions in unfamiliar languages?

Tags: discussion, triage

The Triage queue often includes questions that lack code, MCVE or indication of effort to solve the problem. To me, such a question is unsalvageable regardless of (un)familiarity with the language. According to comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280773/5967807), one should flag a clearly poor question and that [disputed flags are not a problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294475/5967807).

However, comments at some of those questions sometimes indicate that the question clarity depends on language/platform knowledge, leading me to skip.

- Doesn't flagging that ends disputed clutter review queues for those
  who review flags?
- Doesn't skipping questions in unfamiliar
  languages, which might be majority for people like me, waste willingness to review?
- What would be the best practice is reviewing questions in unfamiliar languages?

Comment: Skip. It's the same in all review queues. If you don't know, skip. Releated; [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip). Others that do know the language will review. I know it can feel like you're not helpful in skipping but it's actually more helpful to skip than to choose the wrong option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know how to review it, skip it.

Only chose a review option if you're *absolutely certain* that's the right one.